# Multithreaded application performance

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, multicore

My Java application essentially does this:

- read nThread buffers from a file (1 mb byte arryas)
- create nThread threads that process the buffers
- wait for threads to process data
- write processed data to another file

It is one of those applications that should achieve a theoretical 100% speed boost for each core, but instead, the more threads process the information, the SLOWER it gets!

example:

- 1 thread: 4800 ms
- 2 threads: 10200 ms
- 3 threads: 13400 ms
- 4 threads: 18560 ms
- and so on

Comment: Are you reading the file with multiple thread by chance?

Comment: Do you create many new threads or re-use them?

Comment: Can you show us a small code sample of how you are creating your threads and sending the lines to them?

Comment: I bet he is using the run method instead of start :D

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Your bottleneck is your hard-drive and nothing will make that faster. Some simple pre-optimisation testing would have confirmed that.

Comment: Measure performance in single-thread mode to understand how many time is used for each step (read/process/write) .

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon This is not expected behavior.  If he is IO bound then adding threads won't _help_ but they shouldn't hurt and certainly not that much.

Comment: Following along with @OldCurmudgeon, when you multi-thread something you have to proceed with a theory as to what improvement the extra threads bring. If you are I/O bound (which is typically the bottleneck in any processing), then you would need to see if it is possible to multi-thread I/O access to the file, and still get a valid processing result. For example, can you split the file into 3 regions, and assign a thread to read and process each region?

Comment: the bound is not the hard drive. i measured the time it takes it to load 1 mb of data from the disk, and it's something like 1 or 2 ms, way below the 2 seconds it takes for each thread to complete processing. as someone suggested below, however, it may be a memory bottleneck, or maybe something related to the cpu cache: when 1 thread is running, it has enough cache to hold the data, the code and stuff of other programs running, but when more threads are working, either the cache is full and it keeps accessing memory, or the memory is accessed so many times it creates a bottleneck. or both

Answer (score 1):

Getting that sort of performance as you add threads means that you are doing something really wrong.   Often adding threads will not provide any speed improvement and sometimes can penalize you a bit but adding another thread and doubling the program run time is highly unusual.

Here's some things to investigate:

- As @Tudor mentioned in the comments, you should be reading the input file from a single thread and then dispatching the work to the worker threads.
- You should consider using an `ExecutorService` instead of managing your own threads yourself.  This usually removes a lot of user code and associated bugs.  See [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThread)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29).
- Are you sure you are starting your threads correct?  You should be calling `new Thread(...).start()` and not calling `run()` directly.
- Are you calling `join()` *before* you start your next thread?  You should `start()` all of your threads, dispatch the lines to them, and then `join()` on them at the end.
- Any chance you are sending all of the input lines to all of the threads by accident?  I wouldn't think that this would show the performance numbers however unless you are increasing your output IO as well.

If you show us some of your thread code in your question, we can help more.

Comment: i tried both reusing the same threads and creating new ones, with minimum changes in the order of <1ms

Comment: i am using .start() but not .join() because of how i managed the threads, now i'll give a look at that thread pool, i'll see if it works. thanks a lot

Comment: i just rewrote the application using the thread pool. still no improvements. i called nanotime at the beginning and at the end of the thread that processes the data, and i don't know what to say. the time it takes to a thread to process the data is proportional to the number of running threads, but there are enough cpu cores to run them all simultaneously, and they are running at about 50-60% with 4 threads, so... what the hell is it scheduling to take that long??

Comment: How are you dividing up the lines to be processed.  Any chance you are sending all of the lines to all of the threads?

Comment: Sorry, too much code for me to process.  Can you cut it down to 50-100 lines and post to pastebin.com?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ng416430   this is the code that generates the threads. the run method of those threads is a cycle that is run l times, where l is the number of bytes read from the inputstream

Comment: So even though you are submitting threads, they aren't running as threads -- they are running as `Runnable`.  So `isCompleted()` will never return true.  If you need results then you should use a `Callable<byte[]>` and save the Future<byte[]>` in your list instead of the threads.  `e.execute()` returns the `Future`.  See: http://java-x.blogspot.com/2006/11/java-5-concurrency-callable-and-future.html

Comment: isCompleted does work, it's a method that return true when the thread has processed the data, i made it myself, it's just a get method of a boolean variabile called completed :)

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Have you removed the `sleep()`?  Why is that there?  Also, how much time is spent on each individual integer that you read?  Have you considered reading in 100 ints at once and then passing an array to each thread?

Comment: the sleep is there because while the threads are processing data, the main thread has nothing to do but wait for them to complete. so i put that sleep to avoid wasting processing power in a busy wait. each byte array takes about 2 seconds to process (for 1mb): l is the amount of bytes read from the inputstream, and is passed to the new thread so that it won't process empty bytes in the buffer. unfortunately the size of the inputstream is too big and i can't load too much stuff in memory

Answer (score 0):

A code which hasn't been adequately optimized will usually use up the entire memory bandwidth all by itself. Add another thread using the same unoptimized code on a multi-core processor and they'll split the bandwidth between them and, in addition, run into each other fairly often, further slowing things down.

Gray says "... doubling the program run time is highly unusual." I disagree. That's usually what happens in C code before you start optimizing the memory accesses. I'd say it's highly unusual to not see a slowdown right from the start.

I don't know if sampling is available for Java but that is an obvious place to start.